# Download URL change when file is overwritten in bucket. How to keep original URL

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have successfully managed to create a trigger for cloud storage which resize and overwrite original image file.

```
return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: tempFilePath
}).then(() => {
    return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-resize', '150x150', tempFilePath])
}).then(() => {
    metadata.isResized = true
    return destBucket.upload(tempFilePath,
        {
            destination: path.join(path.dirname(filePath), path.basename(filePath)),
            metadata: { metadata: metadata }
        })
}).then(() => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath))
});
```

However that also change download URL for that file which I store in firestore database

```
const pathRef = storageRef.ref('profileImg/' + uid + '/' + image.name)
        pathRef.put(image).then(() => {
            //Get logo URL
            const starsRef = storageRef.ref().child('profileImg/' + uid + '/' + image.name)
            starsRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                changeProfile({ profile: profile, profileImg: url }).then((result) => {
                    dispatch(progressSuccess(result))
                }).catch((error) => {
                    dispatch(progressFailed(error.message))
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                dispatch(progressFailed(error.message))
            })
```

Is there any way to keep the original download URL in overwritten file? Or is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Isn't the new path just the old path with `-resize` added?

Comment: Hi Doug. No it is a completely different path

Comment: Hi codecubed.io Actually not everything. Just the end of the link right after media&token

media&token=6ddcd967-4213-47f8-badd-74dbd203e783

media&token=8062018c-738b-4271-9c15-a1a2ce40505c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I had to take another approach to this task because I assume that there is no way to keep the original URL. Basically now I do everything (resize image, delete original image, get url, update user database) in one storage trigger function.

```
return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: tempFilePath
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempFilePath)
        return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-resize', '140x140', tempLocalJPEGFile])
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('JPEG image created at', tempLocalJPEGFile)
        metadata.modified = true
        return destBucket.upload(tempLocalJPEGFile,
            {
                destination: JPEGFilePath,
                metadata: { metadata: metadata }
            })
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('JPEG image uploaded to Storage at', JPEGFilePath)
        return destBucket.file(filePath).delete()
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Original file deleted', filePath)
        const logo = storageRef.file(JPEGFilePath)
        return logo.getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: '03-09-2491' })
    }).then((url) => {
        const newRef = db.collection("user").doc(uid)
        return newRef.set({
            profile: {profileImg: url[0]}
        }, {
            merge: true
        })
    }).then(()=> {
        fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
        fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalJPEGFile)
        console.log('User database updated')
        return null
    })
})
```

I'm not sure if this is the best practice so please feel free to comment or update. I also didn't know if there is any better way to get folder name from bucket where the image is stored which is named as user id value (userImg/[userIdHere]/image.jpg) which I needed for updating db so I used old fashion split code

```
const uid = filePath.split("/").slice(1,2).join("")
```

However this trigger will makes the bucket usable only for user images since we can not use trigger for certain folder in a bucket